# Reverse string with non-ASCII characters

Tags: c++, string, unicode, reverse

I want to change the order in the string with special characters like this:

> ZAŻÓŁĆ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ

to

> ŃŹAJ ĄŁŚĘG ĆŁÓŻAZ

I try to use std::reverse

```
std::string text("ZAŻÓŁĆ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ!");
std::cout << text << std::endl;
std::reverse(text.rbegin(), text.rend());
std::cout << text << std::endl;
```

but the output show me that:

> ZAŻÓŁĆ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ!
>
> !\203Ź\305AJ \204\304L\232Ř\304G \206āœû\305AZ  <- reversed string

So i try do this "manually" :

```
std::string text1("ZAŻÓŁĆ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ!");
std::cout << text1 << std::endl;
int count = (int) floorf(text1.size() /2.f);
std::cout << count  << "  " << text1.size() << std::endl;

unsigned int maxIndex = text1.size() - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
{
    char tmp = text1[i];
    text1[i] = text1[maxIndex];
    text1[maxIndex] = tmp;
    maxIndex--;
}
std::cout << text1 << std::endl;
```

But in this case I have a problem in text1.size() because every special character are counted twice:

> ZAŻÓŁĆ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ!
>
> 13  27  <- second number is text1.size()
>
> !\203Ź\305AJ \204\304L\232Ř\304G \206āœû\305AZ

How is the proper way to reverse a string with special characters?

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to use reverse iterators for `std::reverse`. (Not that it changes the results, but nice to know)

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, it won't, if the characters are decomposed. And I'm getting suspicious because that `\304` looks a lot like `U+0304` which is a decomposed diacritic.

Comment: @MSalters: Indeed, good point.

Comment: In all honestly it's a bloody hard problem in Unicode to start with. C++ doesn't help you one bit there. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629183/fully-correct-unicode-visual-string-reversal

Comment: @MSalters IMO just stating the problem properly is hard enough.

Comment: True, just consider reversing "ae" versus reversing "æ"

Answer (score 1):

Your code really does correctly reverse bytes in your string, there's nothing wrong here. The problem, however, is that your compiler stores your literal string "ZAŻÓŁĆ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ!" in UTF-8 encoding.

And UTF-8 stores all characters except those that match ASCII as variable-length **sequences** of bytes. This means that one `char` (one byte) is no longer one character, so reversing `char`'s isn't now the same as reversing characters.

To achieve your goal you have at least two options:

1. Use some utf-8 library that will let you iterate characters instead of bytes. One example is http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/
2. Somehow (and that depends a lot on the compiler and OS you are using) switch to utf-32 encoding that has constant character length and have good old constant-character-size strings without all this crazy variable-character-size troubles.

UPD: A nice link for you: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: utf32 is just delegating the problem to 32 bits, sticking to utf8 should be the right thing

Comment: What does "delegating the problem to 32 bits" even mean?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Some character sequences are too long for utf32

Comment: @Dieter Lücking At the present moment UTF-32 is the only fixed-character-length Unicode encoding and is's unlikely that humanity will ever need more unicode characters in the nearest 1000 years. So I don't think that it will become variable-length in nearest future. And if it doesn't become variable-length, it indeed does solve OP's problem with characters reversal.

Comment: @DieterLücking Name one. (There aren't any in Unicode, *by definition*; the UTF-8 encoding treats any value above 0x10FFFF as invalid *by definition*).

Comment: Though I agree that understanding UTF-8 and sticking to it is good and useful in most cases. People reading our discussion might find this link useful: http://www.utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: All that said, UTF-8 or UTF-whatever here are all irrelevant in the face of combining marks.

Comment: And FWIW, Joel's Unicode article is outdated about UTF-8 going up to 6 bytes. It hasn't been up to 6 bytes for a decade now. (And even if it was correct, those 6 bytes only cover a 31-bit space, not more.)

Answer (score 0):

You might code a reverseUt8 function by yourself:

```
std::string getMultiByteReversed(char ch1, char ch2)
{  
   if (ch == '\xc3') // most utf8 characters
      return std::string(ch1)+ std::string(ch2);
   } else {
      return std::string(ch1);
   }
}

std::string reverseMultiByteString(const std::string &s)
{
    std::string result;
    for (std::string::reverse_iterator it = s.rbegin(); it != s.rend(); ++it) {
       std::string reversed;
       if ( (it+1) != rbegin() && (reversed = getMultiByteReversed(*it, *it+1) ) {
          result += reversed;
          ++it;
       } else {
          result += *it;
       }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can look up the utf8 codes at: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: This code has multiple issues. Please fix it's syntax issues before submitting it

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here. The answer is complex and can depend on exactly what you're trying to do.

First is that (as other answers have stated) if your string is UTF-8 encoded, one Unicode code point may consist of multiple bytes. If you just reverse the bytes, you'll break the UTF-8 encoding. The simplest (though not necessarily the best) fix for this is to convert the string to UTF-32 and reverse the 32-bit code points rather than bytes.

The next problem is that a single grapheme might consist of multiple Unicode code points. For example, a "é" might be encoded as the two code points U+0065 followed by U+0301. If you reverse the order of these, that will break it as the combining character U+301 will now be associate with a different base character. So "Pokémon" reversed this way would become "noḿekoP" with the accent over the "m" instead of the "e".

Now you might think that you can get around this problem by normalizing the string into a composed form first. That has its own problems, however, because not every grapheme can be represented by a single code point. For example, the Canadian flag emoji () is represented by the code point U+1F1E8 followed by the code point U+1F1E6. There is no single code point for it. If you reverse its code points, you get the flag for Ascension Island () instead.

Then you have languages where characters change form based on context, and I don't yet know much about dealing with those.

It may be closer to what you want to reverse *grapheme clusters*. See [UAX29: Unicode text segmentation](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries).

Answer (score -4):

have you tried swapping characters one by one.
For example, if the string length is odd, swap the first character with the last, second with the second last, till the middle character is left. If the string lengt is even, swap 1st with last, 2nd with 2nd last, till both the middle characters are swapped. In that way, the string will be reversed.

Comment: That is exactly what `std::reverse` does, except it does it without you wasting your time writing code, testing code, and fixing problems in that code.